# Can't stop Microsoft.com from detecting my location

Tags: google-chrome, language, privacy

I want to record a screen recording for an English customer. So I don't want any windows or websites to be shown in my local non-English language.

What a frustrating process!

Things I have done:

- Change language settings in Windows 8.1
- Set Windows UI to English
- Disable location aware features in Internet Options
- Disable location detection in Chrome's Privacy settings
- Use CCleaner to delete all cookies

The Internet is now in English, although Google.com was trying to weasel their way back to my local language.

The ONLY website that refuses to honor my settings is Microsoft.com. And I *know* they are ignore my settings because I purchased an Anonymous VPN account *especially* for them and when I use an US EAST connection the website's language is indeed in English.

How do I stop them? **NO** is apparently not enough.

Comment: Microsoft does not sell VPN services...

Comment: Can't you change the language of microsoft.com at the footer of the webpage?

Comment: They detect your location from your IP address. Not nearly as accurate as enabling sending location info on a phone but more than good enough to detect your country.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain you are requesting that Microsoft site using an American ("US East") IP address? If so, the only other thing that might give away your location is the user agent header (http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) sent by your browser. Have you checked what that is? http://www.ipchicken.com will tell you these things.

Comment: Actually, it might be one of the other HTTP headers as well. Maybe HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE. Try to use your browsers developer tools do study the HTTP communication between your browser and Microsoft. They could even be using the character set you say you accept. This website tries to list many of the relevant headers http://myhttp.info/ but a better way is to use your browsers developer tools to see the actual request.

Answer (score -1):

Like you said yourself, the only way to be 100% sure is to use a proxy in an English speaking location when making your screen recording.

Try using the anonymox plug-in in Chrome or Firefox and set it to a proxy from UK or US.

Comment: Can you better explain why this answer fully explains how to accomplish what the author is looking to do?

Comment: The author already knows how to use a proxy since they have already stated that they have used one. The browser plug-in anonomyx simplifies the use of free proxies. No further explanation is needed to solve the authors dilemma.

Comment: He wanted to do it without a proxy or VPN.

Comment: No he did not. And nowhere is his preference for VPN/proxies indicated. He merely indicated that he used a VPN for microsoft.com and that worked.